# Mock framework works with dependency injection framework in unit test

Tags: guice, easymock, roboguice

When I writing tests with EasyMock and Guice framework, I encounter a problem. The code is like:

```
class A {
    B b;

    @Inject
    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
        this.b.addListener(this);
    }
}

class ATest {
    @Inject
    A a;

    B b;

    class InjectionModule extends AbstractModule {
        protected void configure() {
            b = createMock(B.class);
            bind(B.class).toInstance(b);
        }
    }

    public void setUp() {
        createInjector(new InjectionModule()).injectMembers(this);
    }

    public void testSomething() {
        replay(b);
        a.doSomething();
        verify(b);
    }
}
```

In `ATest`, I replace B implementation with a mock object. But when injector creates an instance of A, `B.addListener()` is invoked in `A`'s constructor and unfortunately this invokation is recorded by EasyMock even if I never expect it.

Therefore, my problem is that EasyMock expects me to invoke `B.addListener()` in each testcase in `ATest`. Please give me any suggestions to overcome this. Thanks.

Comment: Finally, I discard the mock framework. After a week of work, I use inheritance to mock class and replace the implementation of test taret with DI framework. Now my unit test is easy to write and more clear.

I believe the philosophy of DI framework is suitable for unit test, it helps me replace the implementation of test target gracefully. On the other hand, mock framework did help me when unit testing, but it is not so powerful like mockito and has many limitations.

Comment: When DI and mock framework can not work smoothly together, I decide to discard the mock framework. Maybe someone else finds helpful when only using mock framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you're trying to unit test a class using a DI framework (which is always painful).

Why don't you just instantiate A yourself and in the process remove 8 lines of code?

Comment: Because you can often use a DI framework to simplify the mocking process for larger code bases.